# C2C commerce data set

Tags: data-request, research, shopping

I'm working on a **research** about recommender systems and I'm looking for a **C2C e-commerce data set**, the data set should contain transaction data with the `buyer id`, `seller id`, `item id` and some `item attributes`. it will be better if it contains some attributes about the seller and the buyer that influences the trust between them.